# If rabin signature uses a hash function then why cant we use that hash function to sign a message?

Tags: hash, signature, hash-signature, rabin-cryptosystem

About Rabin Signature [link](http://publications.csail.mit.edu/lcs/pubs/pdf/MIT-LCS-TR-212.pdf)

According to this paper, the person who wants to sign a message M first appends a random byte string U.
=> M_new = MU
Then uses a compression function to get c = Compression_function(MU) 
Then solves the equation for x,   x(x+b) mod n = c mod n.

Then the signature is (U,x) pair.

My question is why cant we just use c as a signature?

I Assume that 'compression_function' is a collision resistant hash function.

Comment: Hint: how would you verify that signature, and distinguish one made by the authorized signer from one made by anyone else?

Comment: @fgrieu oh thanks. I understand it now.